# Paramiko connection issue

Tags: python, desktop-application, paramiko

I'm writing my first desktop app and I'm struggling with class instances. This app is a simple ftp program using paramiko. What I've set up so far is a connection.py which looks like this...

```
#connect.py

import user, db
import paramiko, time, os

paramiko.util.log_to_file('paramiko-log.txt')
class Connection:
    def __init__(self):
        #Call DB Functions
        database = db.Database()
        #Set Transport
        self.transport = paramiko.Transport((user.hostname, user.port))

        #User Credentials
        username = user.username
        password = user.password
        self.transport.connect(username = username, password = password)

        self.sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(self.transport)

        print "Set your credentials in user.py for now!"
        msg = "Connecting as: %s, on port number %d" % (user.username, user.port)
        print msg

    def disconnect(self):
        print "Closing connection..."
        self.sftp.close()
        self.transport.close()
        print "Connection closed."
```

Pretty straightforward. Connect and disconnect.
This connect.py file is being imported into a main.py (which is my gui)

```
#main.py

import connect
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        windowWidth = 550
        windowHeight = 350

        self.establishedConnection = ""

        connectButton = self.createButton("&Connect", self.conn)
        disconnectButton = self.createButton("&Disconnect", self.disconnect)
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(connectButton, 3, 3)
        grid.addWidget(disconnectButton, 4, 3)
        grid.addWidget(self.createList(), 1, 0, 1, 4)

        self.setLayout(grid)     

        self.resize(windowWidth, windowHeight)
        self.setWindowTitle("FTP Program")

    def conn(self):
        connection = connect.Connection()
        self.establishedConnection = connection

    def disconnect(self):
        self.establishedConnection.disconnect()

    def createButton(self, text, member):
        button = QtGui.QPushButton(text)
        button.clicked.connect(member)
        return button

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Window()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The issue is disconnecting. 
I was thinking `__init__` would create an instance of the `Connection()` class. If you look on main.py you can see that I tried to create the variable `self.connectionEstablished` in order to save the object so I could call disconnect on it later.

Where am I going wrong? I'm fairly new to python and other non-web languages(I spend most of my time writing RoR and php apps).

No errors are shown at any time and I started this app out as a terminal app so I do know that connect.py does work as intended.

Edit: So I guess Senderle got a connection closed message, which is what I'd like to see as well but I'm not. I'll mark a best answer if I see something that solves my problem.

Edit Solved: Pushed connect.py and main.py into one file to simplify things. And for some reason that solved things. So who knows whats going on. I'm still going to hold off on 'best answer'. If someone can tell me why I can't have a split file like that then I'm all ears.

Comment: when is conn() being called? the init function looks like it is only setting the variable to and empty string.  Unless conn() is called, self.establishedConnection will never be setup.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with disconnecting? You say "no errors are shown at any time", but you don't say what goes wrong in which way.

Comment: @Karl R: Looks like conn() is being called via the `connectButton = self.createButton("&Connect", self.conn)` widget.

Comment: Are you certain that `conn` is being called when you press the connect button?  I would try adding `connectButton` and `disconnectButton` as instance variables (i.e., use `self.connectButton = ...` in `__init__`).  The examples I have found seem to all retain a handle on every button.

Comment: @D.Shawley yes that's good advice; but when I tested the code, conn was definitely being called.

Comment: @Elxx, still having problems? I can try to help more but only if you post more information.

Comment: @Elxx, see below for my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the code and it ran fine. I made only a few changes.

First, I didn't know what "user" and "db" are, so I commented out

```
import user, db
```

and

```
database = db.Database()
```

and used my own data for username, password, etc.

Second, the PySide module isn't available via my package manager, so I used PyQt4 instead. It didn't like `grid.addWidget(self.createList(), 1, 0, 1, 4)` so I commented that out, and everything worked as expected.

Further thoughts: When there were connection errors, there was some console feedback consisting of stack traces, but nothing more, and `self.establishedConnection` remained a string, causing `self.establishedConnection.disconnect()` to fail. So perhaps there's a connection problem?

EDIT: Aaaahhhhh, I just saw this: "No errors are shown at any time." Are you running this from a terminal or double-clicking an executable? If you start it from a terminal, I bet you'll see stacktraces in the terminal. The gui doesn't close when the code hits an exception.

EDIT2: If joining the files fixes the problem, then I am certain the problem cannot have anything to do with python itself. This has to be a problem with eclipse. You say that connection.py began as a terminal app, so you must be able to run python apps from the command line. Try the following: put main.py, connect.py, etc. in a directory of their own, open a terminal, and run `python main.py`. If it works as expected, then the problem has something to do with eclipse.

Comment: user was just a file with simple info like username, password, hostname and what not. db was my db.py file which held my crud functions for sqlite. I'm running this from eclipse. It doesn't show backtraces or anything...it just sits there(as far as I can tell).

Comment: @Elxx: Ok, sounds like user and db aren't the issue. I don't know how eclipse works, so I can't advise you there -- but I'm pretty confident that if there's an error, it will show up when you run the program through a terminal.

Comment: @Elxx: Are you using the pydev plugin with eclipse? I tried that and the code still worked. And when it didn't, it displayed a traceback in the console.

Comment: ya im using pydev. I get tracebacks for anything else i purposefully break but just not the disconnect function.

Comment: @Elxx: strange. What exactly are you expecting to happen when you hit the disconnect button? For me, "Closing connection..." and "Connection closed" appear in the console, and that's it. Does that not happen for you?

Comment: @senderle: what? that worked for you? Ya thats exactly whats suppose to happen. I wonder whats going on

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling conn() in the constructor.

Comment: why would you connect in the constructor, when conn is bound to a button?

Comment: @unbeli - I'm sure the answer is in response to "I was thinking __init__ would create an instance of the Connection() class".  Without any further information, the best guess is that the OP might have incorrect expectations.

Comment: @unbeli - I was just answering his question of " I was thinking __init__ would create an instance of the Connection() class"